# Why doesn't Bedrock install on local using composer?

Tags: php, wordpress, ubuntu, wordpress-theming

I am trying to install [Bedrock](https://roots.io/bedrock/docs/installation/) on Local by Flywheel to work on WordPress development locally. I'm facing the following issues.

```
Problem 1
    - squizlabs/php_codesniffer is locked to version 3.7.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - squizlabs/php_codesniffer 3.7.1 requires ext-simplexml * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's simplexml extension.

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-ffi.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

Tried to install using `composer create-project roots/bedrock`.

I was expecting Bedrock would install but didn't.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the proper version of php_codesniffer

It doesn't looks like bedrock needs code_sniffer to be there, so I assume you are trying to install the pack for yourself,

https://github.com/roots/bedrock/blob/master/composer.json
Try deleting json.lock and vendor folder , edit the php_codesniffer version to the correct one in your composer.json file and run composer update/install again.

Besides this, code_sniffer is a checking code standard for php, It is not intended for use in production. So it might not be compatible with bedrock.